# open a map from android sd card

Tags: android, android-maps

Please help ... I have to open a Map of type kml from the sd card ... 
the mime type is "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"
so i used this piece of code :
intent.setType("application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml/*");

I Got this error:
"no application can perform this action"

how to use an application that open a map  ?

Comment: Do you have Google Earth Mobile installed? The normal Google maps app cannot read kml files to my knowledge. This question probably belongs on Android Stack Exchange also, unless I am misunderstanding and you are actually asking how to accomplish this from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Find an application that can open KML files.

Step #2: Install that application on the device.

Step #3: Try your code again, with `ACTION_VIEW` and the right MIME type (presumably the one you have) in the `Intent`.